# Media query madness. How to revert to show an element if to an initial display type when item display is none?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

If posed with the following situation how would you resolve.

Consider the following. You want to hide a visible element when a media query is matched:

```
.myElement {
   display: block;
}
```

and media query to hide it:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
.myElement {
   display: none;
}}
```

Now, if you have the reverse. You want to show a hidden element when a media query is matched.

You set it initially to display none:

```
.myElement {
   display: none;
}
```

and then have a media query you have been using for a while and you want to show it so you use:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
.myElement {
   display: block;
}}
```

However now, many myElements, now uses flex layout and some use block layout so the media query breaks.

Could you have a media query where you can make it show without knowing the element display type?

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
.myElement {
   display: initial;
}}
```

Except since display is not set on the element class how does it know? So you maybe declare that the element uses Flex now but it should start not displayed but restore a previous defined value:

```
.myElement {
   display: flex;
   display: none;
}
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: *you can make it show without knowing the element display type?* --> but *you* set the display type so you should know it

Comment: @TemaniAfif It’s a bit more complex than i mentioned. there’s a few problems. basically i want to make all descendants show on hover. Some are block some are flex.  so on a group i want to use .class > * { display: block or flex }. i want all the descendants to display even though they may be different types. do a hide media query is easy because display is initially set in the style rule. doing reverse is not easy because you start with element display none.

Comment: Why don't you just use `max-width: 1000px` media query for `display: none`? Obviously, it's good to use a mobile-first approach, but for your situation, it looks like a better solution than trying to revert block display type

Answer (score 1):

Since `.myElement` can be either a block or a flex, I'm assuming those properties are applied through other classes. So I've created a `.block` class and a `.flex` class for the demo below.

Create another class `.hide` which will be used to set `display: none`.

Now using JS, remove `.hide` from the element whenever it matches your media query. This will revert the element to whatever it was before, flex or block.

Unfortunately there is no method to remove a class based on what media query you're at, so the JS is necessary.

View this in fullscreen mode:

```js
let mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)");
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.myElement')
mql.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
if (e.matches) {
    /* the viewport is 1000 pixels wide or more */
    console.log("This is a wide screen — more than 1000px wide.");
    elems.forEach((elem) => {
        elem.classList.remove("hide");
    });
} else {
    /* the viewport is less than than 1000 pixels wide */
    console.log("This is a narrow screen — less than 1000px wide.");
    elems.forEach((elem) => {
    elem.classList.add("hide");
    });
}
});
```

```css
* {
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hide {
display: none !important;
}

.myElement {
padding: 5px 10px;
color: white;
}

.block {
display: block;
background-color: #4c40f7;
}

.flex {
display: flex;
background-color: #f74040;
}
```

```html
<div class="myElement block hide">
    <div class="block">This is block 1</div>
    <div class="block">This is block 2</div>
</div>
<div class="myElement flex hide">
    <div class="flex">This is flex 1</div>
    <div class="flex">This is flex 2</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

@Vladislav gave a better suggestion in the comments. If you are applying `display: block` or `display: flex` to `.myElement` through another class, you can just edit those classes directly in the media query, *provided you know which class is applying which property*. If you *don't* know this, and classes are modified dynamically, then the first approach works better.

But if you do know which classes will apply which property, you won't need JS at all. You can simply do the following:

```css
* {
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.myElement {
padding: 5px 10px;
color: white;
}

.block {
display: block;
background-color: #4c40f7;
}

.flex {
display: flex;
background-color: #f74040;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) { 

.block, .flex {
display: none;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="myElement block hide">
    <div class="block">This is block 1</div>
    <div class="block">This is block 2</div>
</div>
<div class="myElement flex hide">
    <div class="flex">This is flex 1</div>
    <div class="flex">This is flex 2</div>
</div>
```